# Chat bots missing profile images

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat

Both the [meta chat bot](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/-433/meta-graphic-design) and [featured Qs chat bot](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/-434/featured-questions-on-graphic-design) seem to be missing their profile images (404 error). It seems that something is messed up in their file path.

Comment: Have it in Mobile Chrome too, v49 on Android M.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be fixed, let me know in a comment if the images are the correct ones.

Comment: I believe the originals filled up a little more of the square. [Here's a comment](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/1240?m=28893731#28893731) by one of them if people want to compare it on an actual comment